# initdb: could not execute command, postgres.exe" --boot -x1 -F ": No error

Tags: windows, postgresql

I have an installation that is failing with the following:

```
 [exec] initdb: could not execute command ""D:/SASHome9.4/SASWebInfrastructurePlatformDataServer/9.4/bin/postgres.exe" --boot -x1 -F ": No error
 [exec] initdb: removing data directory "C:/SAS/EBIServer/Lev1/WebInfrastructurePlatformDataServer/data"
 [exec] Result: 1
```

The account running the installation is an Administrator.  USERS and EVERYONE have full control on D: & C: and all subdirectories, including /WebInfrastructurePlatformDataServer.

The COMSPEC environment variable is correct and points to C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

There is no trailing semi colon and calling %COMSPEC% from the command line returns the correct path and performing the echo "test ok" test returns "test ok".

I'm not sure what else needs to be checked.  Most all of the other pages/blogs/forums I have visited say this is an issue with COMSPEC, but so far my situation does not appear that way.

In the above example \data is not getting created.   The same symptom occurs when we use D:.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to clarify one thing.  Postgres is getting setup "under the covers" as part of the SAS Software installation.  The installer is logged into the system with an administrator ID and runs setup.exe to launch the SAS Software installation.  From there, initdb is called as part of the software configuration.  The version of postgres is 9.1.9.  How does the process call COMSPEC?  DOes it use a USER account or would it be using the Admin account that the SAS installer is running under?

Comment: Hi @user3616014
Have you found a solution to this?
I have the same problem on a Win2012 machine. Tried everything and not getting anywere.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The account running the installation should not be an Administrator, but a user such as postgres, and you also have to change the cmd.exe permission, and make it executable by postgres.